# How to do code reuse for android activities?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

code reuse for activity  is confusing. In normal situation we can design a parent activity and put all common method in it. like follow  :

```
 public class BaseActivity extends Activity{
 @Override
  protected void doExit() {
     showDialog(DIALOG_EXIT_ALTER);
 }
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args) {
     switch (id) {  
     case DIALOG_EXIT_ALTER:
     return new AlertDialog.Builder(BaseUIActivity.this)
         .setTitle("Exit?")
         .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(
                            DialogInterface dialoginterface, int i) {
                    close();
                    }
                })
         .setNeutralButton("No",null).create();
     default:
     return null;
     }
 }
 protected void close() {
     finish();
 }
 }
```

then other activities extend  BaseActivity will show a alertdialog instead of exit immediately when back button press. 
But in android framework there are more than one build-in activites such like PreferenceActivity,ListActivity,ActivityGroup,etc.

if my activity extend those activities then it can't use the common code defined in BaseActivity.because of Java's single inheritance.
So is there other way recommend to do code reuse for activity in android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new class ActivityHelper.

```
public class ActivityHelper {

    Activity activity;

    public ActivityHelper(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args) {
        // do many usefull things
        return result;
    }
}
```

Use it in all your activities.

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle args) {
        return activityHelper(id, args);
    }
```

Comment: ActivityHelper would be a good solution you can find a detailed example here: http://iosched.googlecode.com/hg/android/src/com/google/android/apps/iosched/util/ActivityHelper.java
Examine the whole project to see the flow http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Answer (score 1):

Since `PreferenceActivity`, `ListActivity`, `ActivityGroup` are specialized form of `Activity`, and you have to use them in their relative context.

So IMHO workaround is to have one copy of `Base`+[all above `Activity`] if you have to use them more then one time in your project, and extend your child `ListActivity` or whatever Specialized `Activity` it is.